# CUDA C v. Thrust, am I missing something?

Tags: linux, cuda, thrust, nvcc

I just started learning `CUDA` programming. I was trundling through some simple `CUDA C` examples and everything was going swimmingly. Then! Suddenly! Thrust! I consider myself versed on C++ functors and was taken aback at the difference between `CUDA C` and `Thrust`

I find it hard to believe that

```
__global__ void square(float *a, int N) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (idx < N) {
        a[idx] = a[idx] * a[idx];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

float *aHost, *aDevice;

const int N = 10;
size_t size = N * sizeof(float);

aHost = (float*)malloc(size);
cudaMalloc((void**)&aDevice, size);

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    aHost[i] = (float)i;
}

cudaMemcpy(aDevice, aHost, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

int block = 4;
int nBlock = N/block + (N % block == 0 ? 0:1);

square<<<nBlock, block>>>(aDevice, N);

cudaMemcpy(aHost, aDevice, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("%d, %f\n", i, aHost[i]);
}

free(aHost);
cudaFree(aDevice);
}
```

is equvalent to

```
template <typename T>
    struct square {
    __host__ __device__ T operator()(const T& x) const {
        return x * x;
    }
}; 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const int N = 10;
    thrust::device_vector<float> dVec(N);
    thrust::sequence(dVec.begin(), dVec.end());
    thrust::transform(dVec.begin(), dVec.end(), dVec.begin(), square<float>());
    thrust::copy(dVec.begin(), dVec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Am I missing something? Is the above code being run on the GPU? Thrust is a great tool, but I'm skeptical that it takes care of all the heavy C-style memory management.

- Is the `Thrust` code being executed on the GPU? How can I tell?
- How did `Thrust` eliminate the bizarre syntax of evoking a kernel?
- Is `Thrust` actually evoking a kernel?
- Does `Thrust` automatically handle the thread index computation?

Thanks for your time. Sorry if these are silly questions, but I find it incredulous that the examples I've seen transition instantly from what can be described as a Model T to a M3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Roughly: yes, of course. Thrust is a library, so as all of them are born to make it easier. Its great point is avoiding all explicit CUDA code, which looks strange for rest of programmers, providing a friendly C++-like interface.

Thrust uses GPU, but not *just* GPU. It makes same operations you make if you write your own code, i.e., C/C++ code for allocating memory, copying, set grid and block sizes... and then invokes GPU for executing kernel.

It is a good choice for those who don't want to get inside low level CUDA stuff but to take advantage of GPU parallelism in a simple (but frequent) problem, like vector operations.

Comment: So the `thrust::transform` function evokes my `square` kernel? How does it know how to allocate the threads?

Comment: Yes, it invokes your *functor*, as part of a *kernel* it creates "under the hood". Thrust is an open-source library; you can inspect it yourself.  And there are GPU profiling tools you can use to confirm that thrust is indeed using the GPU. Regarding assignment of threads, it's a common strategy in CUDA programming to assign one thread per output element, when a large amount of output is created.  Looking at your functor and the overall algorithm, I observe that there is a 1:1 relationship between input and output (often true of `transform`), so one thread per data element would make sense.